# How to dynamically select a service in Grails

Tags: spring, grails, dependency-injection, grails-2.0

From my controller I would like to dynamically select a service based on a parameter.

Currently I have a base service and some other services that extent this base service.  Based on the parameter I call a class that does creates a bean name based on the param and eventually calls the following:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.ServletContextHolder as SCH
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsApplicationAttributes as GA

class Resolver {
    def ctx

def getBean(String beanName) {
    if(!ctx) {
        ctx = SCH.servletContext.getAttribute(GA.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
    }
    return ctx."${beanName}"
}
```

}

This returns the service I want.  However I feel rather dirty doing it this way.  Does anyone have a better way to handle getting a service (or any other bean) based on some parameter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ctx."${beanName}"` is added to the `ApplicationContext` metaclass so you can do stuff like `def userService = ctx.userService`. It's just a shortcut for `ctx.getBean('userService')` so you could change your code to

```
return ctx.getBean(beanName)
```

and it would be the same, but less magical.

Since you're calling this from a controller or a service, I'd skip the `ServletContextHolder` stuff and get the context by dependency-injecting the `grailsApplication` bean (`def grailsApplication`) and getting it via `def ctx = grailsApplication.mainContext`. Then pass it into this helper class (remember the big paradigm of Spring is dependency injection, not old-school dependency-pulling) and then it would be simply

```
class Resolver {
   def getBean(ctx, String beanName) {
      ctx.getBean(beanName)
   }
}
```

But then it's so simple that I wouldn't bother with the helper class at all :)