# How to call a Service in a Grails integration test

Tags: grails

This thread describes how to call a Service in a view: [How do I get an instance of a Grails service programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276624/how-do-i-get-an-instance-of-a-grails-service-programmatically)

This describes how to call it in a Servlet: [How do I get an instance of a Grails service programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276624/how-do-i-get-an-instance-of-a-grails-service-programmatically)

This one says how to call it in a Controller: [How to dynamically select a service in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956316/how-to-dynamically-select-a-service-in-grails)

I need to get a handle to my service in an integration test. Is this possible?

Comment: Cant you just put `def myService` in the test and grails should inject it AFAIK

Answer (score 8):

If its an integration test, you have access to the entire runtime so just inject it like you do normally.

```
def someService
```

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [Testing Controllers with Service](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/testing.html#integrationTesting).

**Gist:**
You have to initialize the service (spring bean) to controller in the test.

```
class FilmStarsTests extends GroovyTestCase {
    def popularityService
    void testInjectedServiceInController () {
        def fsc = new FilmStarsController()
        fsc.popularityService = popularityService
        fsc.update()
    }
}
```

Services are autowired in integration tests as in controllers.